# How to use react to listen a loop events with contract?

Tags: reactjs, events, solidity, smartcontracts

I have a solidity contract like this:

```
function Gamer_List()public payable{
   for(uint256 i = 0 ; i < members ; i++){
       emit event_list(i,player[i]);
   }
}
event event_list(address num_id , string player_name);
```

is there any way to use react to get events from a loop?

Comment: Javascript frameworks like web3.js that enables interactions with your smart contract are able to handle events fired by the sc. Read this [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events) for details.

Answer (score 1):

In solidity side you should add indexed modifier in event such like

```
event event_list(address indexed num_id , string player_name);
```

in Javascript side you can do

```
var depositEvent = cryptoExContract.Deposit({_sender: num_id});
depositEvent.watch(function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return;
  }
  // append details of result.args to UI
})
```